# Mongoose findOne() and find() return invalid values, when they should return null / empty list respectively

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I do

```
const currencyFound = await Currency.findOne({some_field_that_does_not_exist_in_any_currency : value});
```

currencyFound is never null, when it logically should be? It seems to be some random document fetched from the Currencies collection, even though none of the documents in the collection, including the one fetched, have a field same as the one specified in the filter for findOne (some_field_that_does_not_exist_in_any_currency).

Similar behaviour when I do

```
const currenciesFound = await Currency.find({some_field_that_does_not_exist_in_any_currency : value});
```

I expect an empty list, but I get ALL the records on the collection!
What's going on?

**UPDATE 1**

if I remove await and `console.log` the result, this is what I get:

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} },
  _executionStack: null,
  mongooseCollection: Collection {
    collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
    Promise: [Function: Promise],
    modelName: 'Currency',
    _closed: false,
    opts: {
      autoIndex: true,
      autoCreate: true,
      schemaUserProvidedOptions: [Object],
      capped: false,
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      '$wasForceClosed': undefined
    },
    name: 'currencies',
    collectionName: 'currencies',
    conn: NativeConnection {
      base: [Mongoose],
      collections: [Object],
      models: [Object],
      config: {},
      replica: false,
      options: null,
      otherDbs: [],
      relatedDbs: {},
      states: [Object: null prototype],
      _readyState: 1,
      _closeCalled: undefined,
      _hasOpened: true,
      plugins: [],
      id: 0,
      _queue: [],
      _listening: false,
      _connectionString: 'mongodb://****:****/****',
      _connectionOptions: [Object],
      client: [MongoClient],
      '$initialConnection': [Promise],
      db: [Db],
      host: '****',
      port: ****,
      name: '****'
    },
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  model: Model { Currency },
  schema: Schema {
    obj: { name: [Object], symbol: [Object] },
    paths: {
      name: [SchemaString],
      symbol: [SchemaString],
      _id: [ObjectId],
      updatedAt: [SchemaDate],
      createdAt: [SchemaDate],
      __v: [SchemaNumber]
    },
    aliases: {},
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: { id: [VirtualType] },
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: { initializeTimestamps: [Function (anonymous)] },
    methodOptions: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: {
      name: [Object],
      symbol: [Object],
      _id: [Object],
      updatedAt: [Function: Date],
      createdAt: [Object],
      __v: [Function: Number],
      id: [VirtualType]
    },
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    '$id': 2,
    mapPaths: [],
    s: { hooks: [Kareem] },
    _userProvidedOptions: { timestamps: true },
    options: {
      timestamps: true,
      typeKey: 'type',
      id: true,
      _id: true,
      validateBeforeSave: true,
      read: null,
      shardKey: null,
      discriminatorKey: '__t',
      autoIndex: null,
      minimize: true,
      optimisticConcurrency: false,
      versionKey: '__v',
      capped: false,
      bufferCommands: true,
      strictQuery: true,
      strict: true,
      pluralization: true
    },
    '$timestamps': { createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: 'updatedAt' },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
    _requiredpaths: [ 'symbol', 'name' ]
  },
  op: 'findOne',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { some_field_that_does_not_exist_in_any_currency: 'GBP' },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: Collection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function: Promise],
      modelName: 'Currency',
      _closed: false,
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'currencies',
      collectionName: 'currencies',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: false,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'currencies'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log` `Ticket.findOne({ ... })` *without* the `await`?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts Added the result to the post. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, did you end up disabling `strictQuery` globally? I'm surprised about the default behavior because a typo in the query filter key can cause devastating bugs.

Comment: The Mongoose maintainer himself has opened an issue to change this default behavior back again: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11861

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose has an option for Schemas called [strictQuery](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery). If this value is set to `true`, fields in the filter that are not part of the schema will be removed from the filter. Its default value is equal to the value of the option [strict](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict), which is `true` by default.

> ```
> const mySchema = new Schema({ field: Number }, { strict: true });
> const MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', mySchema);
> // Mongoose will filter out `notInSchema: 1` because `strict: true`, > meaning this query will return
> // _all_ documents in the 'tests' collection
> MyModel.find({ notInSchema: 1 });
> ```

If you set `strictQuery` to `false`, fields that don't exist should remain as part of the filter.

> ```
> const mySchema = new Schema({ field: Number }, {
>     strict: true,
>     strictQuery: false // Turn off strict mode for query filters
> });
> const MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', mySchema);
> // Mongoose will not strip out `notInSchema: 1` because `strictQuery` is false
> MyModel.find({ notInSchema: 1 });
> ```

Comment: I'm surprised about this default behavior. You can add some really devastating bugs with just a typo in the key of a query filter.