# Filtering in Mongoose / MongoDB 'find' with non-existent value returns all results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose v6.3.8. I might have a basic misunderstanding about how Mongoose / MongoDB works, but if I do...

```
model.find({ nonExistentKey: 'anyValue' });
```

it returns all documents, even though nonExistentKey doesn't show up anywhere in my database.

I was expecting it to return no documents since no documents use nonExistentKey.

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose findOne() and find() return invalid values, when they should return null / empty list respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456923/mongoose-findone-and-find-return-invalid-values-when-they-should-return-nul)

Answer (score 0):

To find all docs which have **nonExistentKey** with any value you can try

```
model.find({ nonExistentKey: { $exists: 1 } });
```

To find all docs which have not to key named **nonExistentKey**

```
model.find({ nonExistentKey: { $exists: 0 } });
```