# Have findOne return null instead of an arbitrary document if the query filter has an invalid key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

When I use Mongoose's `findOne` with a filter that uses a non-existing key, the query returns an arbitrary document (probably the first one in the collection). This can cause some devastating bugs. Why does Mongoose behave this way and is there a way to avoid this? When the key/value combination in the filer doesn't exist, I would expect the query to return no result.

Example:

```
const googleSignupToken = await GoogleSignupToken.findOne({ token: token }).exec();
```

When I accidentally filtered with `{ tokenId: token }` (`tokenId` doesn't exist as a key on this schema), it returned the wrong document. Am I using the wrong query method?

Comment: Sorry, found the answer in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456923/mongoose-findone-and-find-return-invalid-values-when-they-should-return-nul?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You are using equality filter so it matches the documents that either contain token that is `null` or that do not contain the field. Refer to this article for more info: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#equality-filter

You need to make sure the property you are filtering exists:

```js
GoogleSignupToken.findOne({ $and: [{ 'token': { $exists: true } }, { 'token': { $eq: 1231 } }] })
```

Comment: Thank you. On the MongoDB forum, they actually told me that native MongoDB **does** return `null` if the key in the filter doesn't exist. I'm surprised about this default behavior in Mongoose. There is also another option, which is setting `strictQuery` to `false` so invalid keys don't get automatically removed from the query.

Comment: I have run the query similar to yours with a nonexistent field against my MongoDB 4.4 cluster and it returned a document. So it's a bit weird to hear that it might return `null` because it goes against the documented behavior. Nevertheless, setting `strictQuery` on a schema is a great solution if you are using `mongoose`